# Is Chrome Lighthouse Broken for Mobile Testing?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Here are Chrome Lighthouse scores for three top sites: Uber, AirBnB, and Pizza Hut. Testing is conducted with Mobile selected:

[image]

The scores don't seem to match up with the actual mobile page load speed - and seem impossibly low for top high-traffic sites like these.

**UBER**

[image]

**AirBnB**

[image]

**PIZZA HUT**

[image]

Is Chrome Lighthouse broken for mobile testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected. Lighthouse, by default and with the settings you showed, throttles the network speed and CPU (simulated). See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md

Comment: Yes, but I **think** it's just supposed to emulate normal mobile phone network/CPU speeds -- and those sites do work on most mobile phones.

Comment: No, it's meant to emulate low end mobile devices and network speeds.

(source: I'm a core contributor to Lighthouse)

see this nice ~1 minute clip from my colleague for a nice summary on why we target low end devices: https://youtu.be/XxvHY4wC8Co?t=95

Comment: It's awesome to hear from you! Okay, this resolves this question -- much appreciated! Is there a link for info to help developers evaluate the Google PageRank impact (if any) of a low score here?

Comment: you're welcome!


As a lab tool, we're just providing you insights on where you can improve the page experience/metrics. Look to field data (as found in PageSpeed Insights or Search Console) for a closer look into how Google sees the page performance wrt. search signals.

I believe this is the latest on the subject: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2021/04/more-details-page-experience

Comment: Connor, could you please also take a look at my previous Lighthouse question on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805578/understanding-chrome-lighthouse-clear-storage-option)?  I'm trying to understand the "Clear Storage" option.